# Haskel. Проблема с иммутабельностью в рекурсивной функции

Tags: haskell

Пишу небольшую консольную игрушку, есть карта вида:

```
#######
#%....#
#.....#
#######
```

А также функция вечно вызывающая саму себя, этакий mainloop. Каждый вызов функция запрашивает ввод символа - wasd например, и символ % должен перемещаться по карте в соответствующем направлении. Проблема же возникла с обновлением карты в бесконечной рекурсии, в императивных языках я бы просто всегда менял карту, а вот в haskell`e решение я придумать не могу. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандартный способ отслеживать состояние алгоритма от одной итерации к другой - это передавать его в качестве параметра:

```
mainloop currentMap = do
    playerCommand <- readLn
    let newMap = modifyMap currentMap playerCommand
    mainloop newMap

main = mainloop initialMap
```

---

Разумеется в Хаскелле также есть поддержка настоящих изменяемых ячеек памяти, которыми можно пользоваться точно так же, как изменяемыми переменными в других языках. Пожалуй самый простой вариант - это [`IORef`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-16.19/base-4.13.0.0/Data-IORef.html#t:IORef):

```
mainloop mapRef = do
    currentMap <- readIORef mapRef
    playerCommand <- readLn
    let newMap = modifyMap currentMap playerCommand
    writeIORef newMap mapRef
    mainloop mapRef

main = mainloop =<< newIORef initialMap
```

Но, конечно же, в данном случае изменяемые ячейки - это из пушки по воробьям. Их вообще следует избегать по мере возможности, ибо изменяемая память - большой источник ошибок. Хаскель не зря весь неизменяемый, не просто так.